# Shortcode with parametar, but no attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Title probably sounds a bit odd, sorry about that.

I have to use shorcode similar to this this one (simplified):

```
[name=John]
```

to return "Hi John".

I know how I would do this if shortcode was

```
[name first="John"]
```

but is it possible to get value "John" somehow in the code in my first example?

I tried to use

```
$a=shortcode_atts(array(
    'name'      => '',
), $atts);
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: You could use `[name]John[/name]`. Read more on the [documentation page for Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) the closest thing you could do is

```
// Usage [name]John[/name] will give: Hi John.
function name_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return 'Hi '. $content .'.';
}
add_shortcode( 'name', 'name_shortcode' );
```

You could have attributes, but I think this is as close as it gets to what you meant.